# how to get all the table existing in a database

Tags: sqlite, python

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('Db-IMDB.db')
imdb = pd.read_sql_query('''SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables''',conn)
```

but it is giving error:

DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables LIMIT 20 ': no such table: information_schema.tables

any help would be great help

Answer (score 3):

There is no `information_schema` in SQLite as pointed out by @mustaccio.

However, you can get the information you require by using this SQL:

```
SELECT 
    name
FROM 
    sqlite_master 
WHERE 
    type ='table' AND 
    name NOT LIKE 'sqlite_%';
```

See the link [here](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-tutorial/sqlite-show-tables/). Tables which begin with `sqlite_` are SQLite's system tables and are explained [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/sys_tables/index.php). Remember that SQLite databases are single files with all of the data and metadata stored in that one file!

Anyway, there's another problem with your SQL - a `LIMIT` clause makes no sense without being preceded by an `ORDER BY` clause. Quite why one would want the first 20 of an alphabetical list of tables is not clear to me? Normally, `LIMIT`s apply to numerical data - I'm not saying it's an absolute requirement, just puzzling, that's all!

If this is, as your comment suggests, an exploratory look at the data, then use the `.output` command from the `sqlite3` client programme and get a list of all the tables (see [here](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-tutorial/sqlite-export-csv/)). Then you can use the `more` command to browse through this list of tables?

There are a few articles about how to ask questions here on my profile - you might want to take a look?

Comment: yes you are right LIMIT here doesn't make sense. Limit i have been using for some other querry. mistakenly typed in this.

Comment: Verace i didn't understand you query written above. Since i don't know any table name which exists in database what would i write in name in your query

Comment: @LalitJain - see my additions to my answer.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ - yes, but when one is looking at a dictionary, one generally knows the word one is searching for. It's like starting a dictionary search at `a` and moving down through the tome! I think browsing the entire table list as I've suggested in an edit is the way to go here?

Comment: @Verace thank you that query worked!!

Comment: Then please mark my answer as correct so that others with the same issue will be able to find the answer easily - answers marked correct rise to the top! Also, I will get a few points! :-)